# Spring RequestMapping doesn't trigger on .jsp requests

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, request, request-mapping

I have a mix of .jsp and .html template files in my Spring/AngularJS project. Its a fairly huge and old project, that I am not too familiar with.

A request as following triggers the RequestMapping function just fine:

```
http://localhost:8080/templates/secured/html/template.html
```

But the following doesn't trigger the RequestMapping function at all and instead gives 404:

```
http://localhost:8080/templates/secured/html/template.jsp
```

What could be wrong? My RequestMapping function looks like this:

```
 @RequestMapping( value = "templates/secured/**/*.*", method = GET )
  public String findTemplate( HttpServletRequest request, 
                              @RequestParam Map<String,Object> params, Model model ) {

    String url = request.getRequestURI()
      .replaceFirst( "^/templates/secured/", "/inc/" );

    logger.info(url);

    return url;

  }
```

EDIT:

So the request mapping function seems to trigger for pretty much everything EXCEPT .jsp. For example, .jsp1 works.

Comment: Can you show me your spring configuration file. There may be something defined for the response.

Comment: you should also add a .jsp as a suffix in your view resolver configuration. I presume it only has the .html that is why it is able to work with the .html template.

Comment: i think you are missing the context root of your project in the URL ?

Comment: How do I find the spring configuration file or the view resolver configuration in the project? What does the file look like?

Comment: Its an xml file which has an entry similar to the following. > <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

Comment: I tried finding those tags with global search and found none. Instead I found the following code: 
`
    StringHttpMessageConverter stringHttpMessageConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
    stringHttpMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes( asList( TEXT_HTML, TEXT_PLAIN ) ); `

Could this be the reason?

Comment: I found this in a beans.java file. There isn't a single <bean tag in the project.

Comment: So maybe by default it only requestmaps .html requests and I need to allow .jsp requests as well?

Comment: The configuration could also have been made using Java/Annotations, not necessarily an xml file.

Comment: Yes this is the case for us.